# Invalid Length Parameter passed to Left or substring function error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016:

```
select 
    a.ID, v.Comments, 
    left(v.rest, patindex('%[^$0-9]%', v.rest + ' ') - 1) as amount
from 
    Table a 
cross apply
    (values (rtrim(left(Comments charindex('$', Comments-1 )),
            stuff(Comments, 1, charindex('$', Comments) -1, ''))) v (Comments, rest)
where 
    ID v.Comments = 'AAAAAAAAAAA MAXIMUM LIABILITY $67,650 NO LONGER QUA'
```

I am getting an error

> Invalid Length parameter passed to Left or substring function.

My objective is to split string and numeric value such as

```
AAAAAAAAAAA MAXIMUM LIABILITY          67,650
```

Below is an example of data in `Comments` column of my table

```
'AAAAAAAAAAA MAXIMUM LIABILITY $67,650 NO LONGER QUA'
'BBBBBBBBBBB MAXI   LILIABILITY $$44,77.00-LAND
'CCCCCCCCCCC MAXIU  LIABILITY   $12,44.90"
```

Comment: Always best to add a "Fail-Safe" to your charindex.   For example:  charindex('$', Comments+'$')    Notice the +'$'

Comment: HI John.  I am trying my best but not working.

Comment: You can use `NULLIF(PATINDEX(...), 0)` in case it can't find a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some typo mistakes on the query you posted on the cross apply part. also i added a comma (,) to the patindex for it to include the all price.

```
select 
    a.ID, v.Comments, 
    left(v.rest, patindex('%[^$0-9,]%', v.rest + ' ') - 1) as amount
from a 
cross apply
    (values (rtrim(left(Comments, charindex('$', Comments)-1 )),
            stuff(Comments, 1, charindex('$', Comments) -1, ''))) v (Comments, rest)
```

if you want you can also add your where but correctly.

```
where a.Comments = 'AAAAAAAAAAA MAXIMUM LIABILITY $67,650 NO LONGER QUA'
```

here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/abe08/8) to show you how it works

Comment: Thank You so much. its working. is there any way to skip $? need only 67,650 . Thanks in advance

Comment: I see that you also have period ('.') for cents. so i added it to the patindex, and for the $ sign i just added a replace. `REPLACE(left(v.rest, patindex('%[^$0-9,.]%', v.rest + ' ') - 1),'$','') as amount`.

Comment: Thanks Yair. Working 100%